# How to transfer push notification from one bundle id to another bundle id?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification

I want to transfer my all push notification from one bundle id to another bundle id

For example :-  i have one app which is bundle is is `com.example.id1` now i want to transfer all push notification from `com.example.id1` to `com.example.id2`.
can any buddy help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. You can not transfer all push notification from one `com.example.id1` to `com.example.id2`. I have find  but not getting solution. You should go through other way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible from my point.Because at one time, there is only one application runing forground, other apps will be frozen in background. You push a notification in app1, other apps in the background can not receive it. Of course, there may be some trick can do that, you have to find out.Good luck.

Comment: after transferring push notification to another id i want to delete old app from app store.and there will be never case that both app will be there on the same device.